# Dividing values from 2 different datasets

Tags: sql, reporting-services, lookup, iif

I am trying to divide 2 different fields from 2 different datasets.  Also using a `lookup` in the statement but for some reason it does the `lookup` part of the expression but doesn't do the division part.  Any ideas?

```
=IIF(Fields!PACKSHORT_DESC.Value = "EA",(LOOKUP(TRIM(Fields!PRODUCT_CODE.value), TRIM(Fields!item.value),Fields!tcost.value,"Cost")/Fields!NO_OF_EACHES.Value),(LOOKUP(TRIM(Fields!PRODUCT_CODE.value), TRIM(Fields!item.value),Fields!tcost.value,"Cost")))
```

Comment: If I write it like this it will perform the division but I don't get the correct number:

=IIF(Fields!PACKSHORT_DESC.Value = "EA",(Fields!NO_OF_EACHES.Value/LOOKUP(TRIM(Fields!PRODUCT_CODE.value), TRIM(Fields!item.value),Fields!tcost.value,"Cost")),(LOOKUP(TRIM(Fields!PRODUCT_CODE.value), TRIM(Fields!item.value),Fields!tcost.value,"Cost")))

Comment: What is the value of `Fields!NO_OF_EACHES.Value`? Is it 1?

Answer (score 0):

Get it to output the two numbers you are trying to divide first to see if they are pulling through correctly first, assign them names and then divide them instead.